# Range of Timestamps

Tags: r, timestamp, posixct

I've got two datasets, both datasets have similar timestamps.
When I print the range (with **range()** ) for the first dataset, I get the range of timestamps without problems. But when I do it for the second timestamp, I get "NA, NA". This is the format of the second dataset:
[format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JxZT.png)

Am I missing something?

Kind regards,
Daniel

Comment: Do you have any NA values in the second data set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely due to there being one or more `NA` values in your second data set. Even a single `NA` will cause the output of `range` to be `c(NA ,NA)`, as we can see in this toy example:

```r
x  <- as.POSIXct(c("2020-01-01 20:00:00", 
                   "2020-01-02 20:00:00", 
                   "2020-01-03 20:00:00"))

range(x)
#> [1] "2020-01-01 20:00:00 GMT" "2020-01-03 20:00:00 GMT"

x[2] <- NA

range(x)
#> [1] NA NA
```

The solution is to use the `na.rm` argument in `range`:

```r
range(x, na.rm = TRUE)
#> [1] "2020-01-01 20:00:00 GMT" "2020-01-03 20:00:00 GMT"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>